# Why the hair particles only have 4 sections when I set segments to 12?

Tags: particles, hair

Why does the comb ignore some vertices? Or rather, why half the control points are fake? Only every 3rd one reacts to combing...

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segments are only guides. You can increase or decrease stands resolution any time that you want (Instead of segments, that's locked after you start editing them), for example, when you want either to improve quality, or speed up viewport performance.

Note: all settings mean subdivision, adding one doubles point count.

For particle edit, increase **Path steps** in **Viewport display** in **Tool settings**:

[image]

For other modes, **Strand steps** in **Viewport display** in **Particle settings**:

[image]

For final render **Path** → **Steps** in **Render** in **Particle settings**:

[image]